# Netcdf dataset conversion from seconds from starting time to utc hours

Tags: python, time, netcdf4

I am working with a netcdf format code and I need to convert the time from seconds from the starting time (2016-01-01 00:00:00.0) to time in UTC. I'm fairly new to all of this so I am really struggling!

I have tried using the `num2date` from `netCDF4`.

```py
from netCDF4 import date2num , num2date, Dataset
time=f.variables['time'][:]
dates=netCDF4.num2date(time[:],time.units)
print(dates.strftime('%Y%m%d%H') for date in dates)
```

> AttributeError: 'MaskedArray' object has no attribute 'units'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you extract `time` from the variables in `time=f.variables['time'][:]`, it will lose it's associated unit (time is just a masked array, as the error says).
What you have to feed to `num2date()` is `variables['time'].units`, e.g.

```py
from netCDF4 import date2num, num2date, Dataset
file = ... # your nc file

with Dataset(file) as root:
    time = root.variables['time'][:]
    dates = num2date(time, root.variables['time'].units)
    ## directly get UTC hours here:
    # unit_utchours = root.variables['time'].units.replace('seconds', 'hours')
    ## would e.g. be 'hours since 2019-08-15 00:00:00'
    # utc_hours = date2num(dates, unit_utchours)

# check:
print(dates[0].strftime('%Y%m%d%H'))
# e.g. prints 2019081516
```

...to get the dates as a number, you could e.g. do

```py
num_dates = [int(d.strftime('%Y%m%d%H')) for d in dates]
# replace int with float if you need floating point numbers etc.
```

...to get the dates in UTC hours, see the commented section in the first code block. Since the dates array contains objects of type [datetime.datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html), you could also do

```
utc_hours = [d.hour+(d.minute/60)+(d.second/3600) for d in dates]
```

Comment: just found a very similar question was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33989979/10197418).

Comment: When I do that, I get this error  'KeyError: <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float64 time(time)
    standard_name: time
    units: seconds since 2016-01-01 00:00:00.0 UTC
unlimited dimensions: time
current shape = (103384,)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used'

Comment: which line throws the error? `time = ...` or `dates = ...`? if it's the second, you could try to use `time.data`

Comment: its the time=… I think it might have to do with it being a float, but I really am not sure

Comment: hm... if it's really this line, the error should also be thrown in the version of the code you posted in the question (in `time=f.variables['time'][:]`). float format is fine btw.

Comment: I got it to work, but its giving me very strange values when I plot it like 0001-01-18 when it should be 2016-07-18 at 16:39:41

Comment: Sounds strange, but hard to tell without an example file. If you can share a file, I could have a look.

Comment: I actually got it to work, however its only reading for one index, how do I get it to read for the entire array?

Comment: you mean `print(dates[0].strftime('%Y%m%d%H'))`? I just put this line there to see if the output is ok. it just prints `dates` at index 0. to print all lines, do e.g. `for d in dates: print(d.strftime('%Y%m%d%H'))`

Comment: yes! I actually need the time in decimals in order to plot it right.

Comment: One last question, I need the data in the format (H+(M/60)+(seconds/3600)). How would i convert this into that? I want to get this figured out because this is only one of my data sets out of many to. I can do it "manually" but I don't want to do that everytime.

Comment: Also, you have been super helpful!

Comment: you mean utc hours? I've added two options how to get those to my answer. you could either get it using the `date2num` function from the netCDF package or run another list comprehension. I'd say `netcdf` is not the easiest data format to start working with, so I'm glad if I could help. Once you get used to it, it's a pretty neat format ;-)