# Convert NetCDF file to CSV or text using Python

Tags: python, csv, text, netcdf, netcdf4

I'm trying to convert a netCDF file to either a CSV or text file using Python. I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28420988/how-to-read-netcdf-file-and-write-to-csv-using-python/28430599#28430599) but I am still missing a step (I'm new to Python). It's a dataset including latitude, longitude, time and precipitation data.

This is my code so far:

```
import netCDF4
import pandas as pd

precip_nc_file = 'file_path'
nc = netCDF4.Dataset(precip_nc_file, mode='r')

nc.variables.keys()

lat = nc.variables['lat'][:]
lon = nc.variables['lon'][:]
time_var = nc.variables['time']
dtime = netCDF4.num2date(time_var[:],time_var.units)
precip = nc.variables['precip'][:]
```

I am not sure how to proceed from here, though I understand it's a matter of creating a dataframe with pandas.

Answer (score 16):

I think `pandas.Series` should work for you to create a CSV with time, lat,lon,precip.

```
import netCDF4
import pandas as pd

precip_nc_file = 'file_path'
nc = netCDF4.Dataset(precip_nc_file, mode='r')

nc.variables.keys()

lat = nc.variables['lat'][:]
lon = nc.variables['lon'][:]
time_var = nc.variables['time']
dtime = netCDF4.num2date(time_var[:],time_var.units)
precip = nc.variables['precip'][:]

# a pandas.Series designed for time series of a 2D lat,lon grid
precip_ts = pd.Series(precip, index=dtime) 

precip_ts.to_csv('precip.csv',index=True, header=True)
```

Comment: Thank you!! This was perfect

Comment: You're welcome. You should accept the answer for future readers.

Comment: It gives me `ValueError: Data must be 1-dimensional`. this line `pd.Series(precip, index=dtime) `.

Comment: Base on Pandas documenation -> pandas.Series is One-dimensional ndarray with axis labels (including time series). That's why it raise ValueError. Alternative solution is using pandas.DataFrame.

Answer (score 7):

```
import xarray as xr

nc = xr.open_dataset('file_path')
nc.precip.to_dataframe().to_csv('precip.csv')
```

Comment: Can you provide more clarity of why you wrote this code compared to the question being asked? How does this code give an answer to the question?

Comment: The popular answer didn't work for me. I am not sure why (maybe something I did wrong?). It seems that xarray library provides a solution in fewer lines of code. This alternative may save time for some people, as it did for me.

Comment: Regarding the other answer which didn't work. I tried it on a standard NOAA mslp netCDF file, https://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/thredds/fileServer/Datasets/ncep.reanalysis2/surface/mslp.2018.nc, and obtained the following error at the 2nd last line:

Comment: >>> # a pandas.Series designed for time series of a 2D lat,lon grid
... precip_ts = pd.Series(precip, index=dtime)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\dav500\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 262, in __init__
    raise_cast_failure=True)
  File "C:\Users\dav500\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 658, in sanitize_array
    raise Exception('Data must be 1-dimensional')
Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional

Comment: Thank you so much this worked for me so perfectly! I have struggled for days but you saved me!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your requirements, you may be able to use Numpy's `savetxt` method:

```
import numpy as np

np.savetxt('lat.csv', lat, delimiter=',')
np.savetxt('lon.csv', lon, delimiter=',')
np.savetxt('precip.csv', precip, delimiter=',')
```

This will output the data without any headings or index column, however.

If you do need those features, you can construct a DataFrame and save it as CSV as follows:

```
df_lat = pd.DataFrame(data=lat, index=dtime)
df_lat.to_csv('lat.csv')

# and the same for `lon` and `precip`.
```

Note: here, I assume that the date/time index runs along the first dimension of the data.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately this didn't work - I decided to just extract all the latitudes and longitudes I was using in my other dataset, and looped over that to get the time series of each place. Like in the link I provided above. Time consuming, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

alternative to xarray library:

```
import netCDF4
precip_nc_file = r'file_path\file_name.nc'
nc = netCDF4.Dataset(precip_nc_file, mode='r')
cols = list(nc.variables.keys())
list_nc = []
for c in cols:
    list_nc.append(list(nc.variables[c][:]))
df_nc = pd.DataFrame(list_nc)
df_nc = df_nc.T
df_nc.columns = cols
df_nc.to_csv("file_path.csv", index = False)
```