# Convert Precipitation Data netcdf file to csv Using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, netcdf4

I'm attempting to convert a netcdf (*.nc) (classic format) to CSV. This file is taken from the NOAA precipitation data set.

I found helpful code in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44359869/convert-netcdf-file-to-csv-or-text-using-python); however, when I run it I get this exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./test2.py", line 31, in
>   
>       precip_ts = pd.Series(precip, index=dtime)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line
>   275, in **init**
>       raise_cast_failure=True)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line
>   4165, in _sanitize_array
>       raise Exception('Data must be 1-dimensional') Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional

Here is the test2.py script (same as post referenced above):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7

import netCDF4
import pandas as pd

precip_nc_file = 'precip.V1.0.2006.nc'
nc = netCDF4.Dataset(precip_nc_file, mode='r')
nc.variables.keys()

lat = nc.variables['lat'][:]
lon = nc.variables['lon'][:]
time_var = nc.variables['time']
dtime = netCDF4.num2date(time_var[:],time_var.units)
precip = nc.variables['precip'][:]

# a pandas.Series designed for time series of a 2D lat,lon grid
precip_ts = pd.Series(precip, index=dtime)

precip_ts.to_csv('precip.csv',index=True, header=True)
```

It is failing at the Pandas Series call. Can you give me any guidance why the pandas is failing; I thought it is supposed to handle 2D data!

The end result I'm looking for is a CSV file with each line having lon, lat, datetime, precip value

Answer (score 0):

Here, `pd.Series()` seems to expect a 1-D object. Whereas the entire masked arrays are more than 1-D. So to access the array part of interest, it could be added by a '`.data`' etc. The code below shows how to save `precip_ts` to `csv`. I do not know enough about the how the '`.nc`' file is structure that I downloaded from [here](https://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/thredds/fileServer/Datasets/cpc_us_precip/precip.V1.0.2006.nc) (`precip.V1.0.2006.nc`). Because there are unequal number of elements in the resulting series. Therefore it is difficult to know which values would be in the same row with others. For example: `lat` has 120 values wherease `lon` has 300 values. On the other hand, if all the arrays were of the same length, then they could be combined into a single pandas dataframe and then saved as a `csv` file (code the very bottom).

**Import libraries**

```
import netCDF4
import pandas as pd
import numpy.ma as ma
```

**Code from the question repeated below**

```
lat = nc.variables['lat'][:]
lon = nc.variables['lon'][:]
time_var = nc.variables['time']
dtime = netCDF4.num2date(time_var[:],time_var.units)
precip = nc.variables['precip'][:]

precip_nc_file = 'precip.V1.0.2006.nc'
nc = netCDF4.Dataset(precip_nc_file, mode='r')
nc.variables.keys()
```

**Edit line below: Replace `dtime` with `dtime.data` to access masked array**

```
precip_ts = pd.Series(dtime.data, index=dtime)
```

**Save as .csv**

```
precip_ts.to_csv('precip.csv',index=True, header=True)
```

[image]

Only if all values of different series have same length then the code below could be used to save all of them into a single dataframe. This did not work for me because the downloaded file created series of unequal lengths.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'lat': lat,
    'lon': lon,
    'dtime': dtime,
    'precip': precip 
})
df.head(2)
```