# Change data source from THREDDS Catalouge for NetCDF

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap, netcdf4, noaa, pygrib

Hi i am using this code from here [How to read NetCDF file and write to CSV using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28430599/9234311) I want to be able to pull out the "Mean_period_of_swell_waves_ordered_sequence_of_data" from from the [THREDDS Catalog here](http://thredds.ucar.edu/thredds/dodsC/grib/NCEP/WW3/Global/Best.html) but am recieving the below error. I am using Canopy

Any ideas why?
Thanks Alec

```
IndexErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
/home/GRIB-extract-SWPER.py in <module>()
     73 #vname = 'surf_el'
     74 var = nc.variables[vname]
---> 75 hs = var[istart:istop,iy,ix]
     76 tim = dtime[istart:istop]
     77 
netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx in netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable.__getitem__ (netCDF4/_netCDF4.c:39739)()
netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx in netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable._get (netCDF4/_netCDF4.c:49789)()
IndexError:
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by changing

```
var = nc.variables[vname]
hs = var[istart:istop,iy,ix]
tim = dtime[istart:istop]
```

to

```
var = nc.variables[vname]
tp = var[istart:istop,iy,ix]
tim = dtime[istart:istop]
```